# How to control volume in chrome packaged app

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is it possible to control the audio of a chrome app window with say, an audio slider? Is it possible with Javascript or Jquery?

Comment: Depends on the source. And is it your app window?

Comment: Is that some media you play, or is it some media in a `<webview>` on a page you don't control?

Comment: Yes @DanielHerr I want to control the app's window audio